# How to count hours in the given intervals

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a dataset with start-time and end-time of using the service. About 1000 rows totally.
I need to count the number of hours in any given interval.

Dataset:

```
   court_number       start_time         end_time  service
1:      court 2 2020-03-01 11:00:00 2020-03-01 12:30:00  booking
2:      court 3 2020-03-01 12:30:00 2020-03-01 13:30:00 coaching
3:      court 1 2020-03-01 11:00:00 2020-03-01 13:00:00  booking
4:      court 5 2020-03-01 12:00:00 2020-03-01 16:00:00  booking
5:      court 5 2020-03-01 16:30:00 2020-03-01 18:30:00 coaching
```

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(court_number = c('court 2','court 3','court 1','court 5','court 5'),
            start_time = c('2020-03-01 11:00:00', '2020-03-01 12:30:00', '2020-03-01 11:00:00', '2020-03-01 12:00:00', '2020-03-01 16:30:00'),
            end_time = c('2020-03-01 12:30:00', '2020-03-01 13:30:00', '2020-03-01 13:00:00', '2020-03-01 16:00:00', '2020-03-01 18:30:00'),
            service = c('booking','coaching','booking','booking','coaching'))
```

I want to count, for example, hours in the interval from "12:00" to "17:00".
So, I need to create a column with hours from 12 to 17:

```
   court_number       start_time         end_time  service interval_12_17
1:      court 2 2020-03-01 11:00:00 2020-03-01 12:30:00  booking            0,5
2:      court 3 2020-03-01 12:30:00 2020-03-01 13:30:00 coaching              1
3:      court 1 2020-03-01 11:00:00 2020-03-01 13:00:00  booking              1
4:      court 5 2020-03-01 12:00:00 2020-03-01 16:00:00  booking              4
5:      court 5 2020-03-01 16:30:00 2020-03-01 18:30:00 coaching            0,5
```

I've read a lot of similar resolved issues here at stackoverflow, but due to the fact that I am newbie to R, it didn't help me =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We convert the 'time' columns to `Datetime` class, get the `difftime` of `pmin` of the 'Time' for 'end_time' and "17:00:00" and the `pmax` of the 'start_time' and "12:00:00"

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
dt %>%
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with('time')), ymd_hms) %>% 
    mutate(interval_12_17 = difftime(pmin(as.ITime(end_time), 
           as.ITime("17:00:00")),
         pmax(as.ITime(start_time),as.ITime("12:00:00")), unit = 'hour'))
#   court_number          start_time            end_time  service interval_12_17
#1:      court 2 2020-03-01 11:00:00 2020-03-01 12:30:00  booking      0.5 hours
#2:      court 3 2020-03-01 12:30:00 2020-03-01 13:30:00 coaching      1.0 hours
#3:      court 1 2020-03-01 11:00:00 2020-03-01 13:00:00  booking      1.0 hours
#4:      court 5 2020-03-01 12:00:00 2020-03-01 16:00:00  booking      4.0 hours
#5:      court 5 2020-03-01 16:30:00 2020-03-01 18:30:00 coaching      0.5 hours
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
dt[, interval_12_17 := difftime(pmin(as.ITime(end_time), as.ITime("17:00:00")),
        pmax(as.ITime(start_time),as.ITime("12:00:00")), unit = 'hour')][]
#    court_number          start_time            end_time  service interval_12_17
#1:      court 2 2020-03-01 11:00:00 2020-03-01 12:30:00  booking      0.5 hours
#2:      court 3 2020-03-01 12:30:00 2020-03-01 13:30:00 coaching      1.0 hours
#3:      court 1 2020-03-01 11:00:00 2020-03-01 13:00:00  booking      1.0 hours
#4:      court 5 2020-03-01 12:00:00 2020-03-01 16:00:00  booking      4.0 hours
#5:      court 5 2020-03-01 16:30:00 2020-03-01 18:30:00 coaching      0.5 hours
```

Comment: Thanks  you very much for the suggested logic.

In the first solution, I was even able to figure it out =) It's working great. 

The second solution is still difficult for me to understand. What is there - vectors, factors ... This remains to be studied =)

Comment: @makstu The second solution is directly during the `pmax``pmin` on the Time converted columns, and taking the `difftime`, on it to assign (`:=`) t to new column